# XCode: Enter edit mode in numeric up/down box

Tags: macos, xcode

I am using the attributes inspector in XCode (7.2) to change some values of a SpriteKit element. When I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> the numeric up/down box is highlighted (see image below), but when I start typing the new value, all that happens is that my mac makes a disgruntled noise. So the question is: How do I enter edit mode of this box without using the mouse. I have tried pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: From what I can tell (I may be wrong), this is only an Issue in the SpriteKit Scene Editor, Not anywhere else in IB/Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply an error of the SpriteKit and I do not believe that there is another way to do it without using the mouse because of this. However you can try holding down the mouse button to change it by larger increments or just double click it.